# Specify AppSettingsReader() to look in different app.config for key

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm using the `AppSettingsReader()` method to get a value from a given key in the `app.config` file:

```
var value = new AppSettingsReader().GetValue("SomeKey", typeof(string)) as string;
```

This is done in a class which is in a seperate assembly with its own `app.config` file. Now if I specify the key/value pair in this `app.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SomeKey" value="MyValue" />
</appSettings>
```

It throws the error:

> "The key 'SomeKey' does not exist in the appSettings configuration section."

Because it looks in the `App.config` file from my main application which is, as stated before, in a different assembly. When I put my key/value pairs in there it works properly.

---

Is there a way of telling `AppSettingsReader()` to look in the `app.config` of the assembly from which it is called and not in the main (parent) assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case you can use the [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It allows you to open configuration files from various places. To open a .config file, other than the one from the .exe, you could use the method `OpenMappedExeConfiguration`.

```
string pathToOtherConfigFile = ""; //you need to specify the path 
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = pathToOtherConfig;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var value = config.AppSettings["SomeKey"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This seems like a good approach. But I have one more problem: How to get the path of the `app.config` in my external assembly? This seems like a simple stupid question but every approach gets me into the directory of my main application and not into the directory of the external assembly.